# Prove $0\leqq x^{2}+ y^{2}- 2\,x^{2}y^{2}+ 2\,xy\sqrt{1- x^{2}}\sqrt{1- y^{2}}\leqq 1$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Prove
$$0\leqq x^{2}+ y^{2}- 2\,x^{2}y^{2}+ 2\,xy\sqrt{1- x^{2}}\sqrt{1- y^{2}}\leqq 1 \tag{1}$$
with 
$$\left | x \right |,\,\left | y \right |\leqq 1 \tag{2}$$
My normal work
$$\begin{cases} \left | x \right |\leqq 1 \Rightarrow -\,1\leqq x\leqq 1 \Rightarrow x\equiv \cos\alpha\,(\,0\leqq \alpha\leqq \pi\,) \\ \left | y \right |\leqq 1 \Rightarrow -\,1\leqq y\leqq 1 \Rightarrow y\equiv \cos\beta\,(\,0\leqq \beta\leqq \pi\,) \\ P\equiv x^{2}+ y^{2}- 2\,x^{2}y^{2}+ 2\,xy\sqrt{1- x^{2}}\sqrt{1- y^{2}} \end{cases}$$
$$\Rightarrow P= \cos^{\,2}\alpha+ \cos^{\,2}\beta- 2\,\cos^{\,2}\alpha\cos^{\,2}\beta+ 2\,\cos\alpha\cos\beta\sqrt{1- \cos^{\,2}\alpha}\sqrt{1- \cos^{\,2}\beta}$$
Otherwise
$$\begin{cases} \sqrt{1- \cos^{\,2}\alpha}= \left | \sin\alpha \right |= \sin\alpha\,(\,\because\,0\leqq \alpha\leqq \pi\,) \\ \sqrt{1- \cos^{\,2}\beta}= \left | \sin\beta \right |= \sin\beta\,(\,\because\,0\leqq \alpha\leqq \pi\,) \end{cases}\begin{cases} \cos^{\,2}\alpha= 1- \sin^{\,2}\alpha \\ \cos^{\,2}\beta= 1- \sin^{\,2}\beta \end{cases}$$
$$P= \cos^{\,2}\alpha+ \cos^{\,2}\beta- 2\,\cos^{\,2}\alpha\cos^{\,2}\beta+ 2\,\cos\alpha\cos\beta\sin\alpha\sin\beta$$
The equality condition is
$$\alpha+ \beta= \frac{\pi}{2},\,3\,\frac{\pi}{2}$$
I tried to solve the trigonometric equation of
$$\begin{cases} \cos^{\,2}\alpha+ \cos^{\,2}\beta- 2\,\cos^{\,2}\alpha\cos^{\,2}\beta+ 2\,\cos\alpha\cos\beta\sin\alpha\sin\beta= 1 \\ \cos^{\,2}\alpha+ \cos^{\,2}\beta- 2\,\cos^{\,2}\alpha\cos^{\,2}\beta+ 2\,\cos\alpha\cos\beta\sin\alpha\sin\beta= 0 \end{cases}$$
but without success. I need to the help! Thanks!

**Little idea**

How about using vector?
$$\begin{cases} \vec{a}= (\,a_{\,1},\,a_{\,2}\,) \\ \vec{b}= (\,b_{\,1},\,b_{\,2}\,) \end{cases}$$
$$\Rightarrow \left [ \,0\leqq (\,\vec{a}\,.\,\vec{b}\,)^{\,2}\leqq \left | \vec{a} \right |^{\,2}\left | \vec{b} \right |^{\,2}= 1\Leftrightarrow 0\leqq (\,a_{\,1}b_{\,1}+ a_{\,2}b_{\,2}\,)^{\,2}\leqq (\,a_{\,1}^{\,2}+ a_{\,2}^{\,2}\,)(\,b_{\,1}^{\,2}+ b_{\,2}^{\,2}\,)= 1\right ]$$
I can't continue!

Comment: Your question is actually better in terms of context... I guess you can leave it alone.

Comment: Btw, I found [it](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%240%5Cle%20x%5E2%2By%5E2-2x%5E2y%5E2%2B2xy%5Csqrt%7B1-x%5E2%7D%5Csqrt%7B1-y%5E2%7D%24&p=1) via approach 0. You may try it next time.